# Not Able to Make SSL Connection

Tags: android, ssl

I am using below code for making SSL connection.

```
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream caInput = mcontext.getAssets().open("idashboard.cer");
        Certificate ca = null;
        try {
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate)   ca).getSubjectDN());
        }catch (CertificateException e4) {
            e4.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try{
                caInput.close();}catch (Exception e5){
                e5.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

        // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf =   TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        // Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
        URL murl = new URL("My URL Here");
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection =
                (HttpsURLConnection)murl.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new NullHostNameVerifier());
        urlConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new NullHostNameVerifier());
        urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream(); //GETTING ERROR AT THIS LINE


        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
```

At thE input stream line(InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();) it goes to verify method of NullHostNameVerifier() and when it returns true don't know what happened it comes to device home screen, I dont know its a crash or what as I don't get crash popup.

Here is the code for hostnameVerifier

```
public class NullHostNameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier {

    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {

        return true;
    }

}
```

I am poor in networking, Not able to understand what is happening. Also this request I have to make as get and post both

Am I missing any line of code? Also how can I make get and post request and how can I parse response from input stream

Any help?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you downloaded the certificate in base64 format?

Comment: yes. its in base64 format

Comment: have you handled the exception? If the SSL connection fails, it should raise an exception

Comment: Whole code is in try catch block!!

Comment: post your logs.